# SQL query for highest netpay among the employees

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-limit

SQL query to display employees records whose netpay is greater than any other employee. Display name,salary,commission,netpay and manager name.
Exclude if manager name is null.
Netpay=salary+commission.

Table:

- `employees` -- commission, dep_id, emp_id, emp_name, hire_date, job_name, manager_id, salary

This is my query:

```
SELECT e.emp_name, e.salary, e.commission, (e.salary+e.commission) AS netpay, x.emp_name
FROM employees e
INNER JOIN employees x ON x.emp_id = e.manager_id
WHERE (e.salary+e.commission) = (SELECT MAX(salary+commission) FROM employees where manager_id IS NOT NULL);
```

I'm not getting the test cases cleared for the above query. can any one help me out to solve this.

[employee table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWmm6.png)

The output I'm getting is

| emp_name | salary | commission | netpay | manager |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tucker | 1600 | 7000 | 8600 | blaze |

I think this the max value among the records but still i have no idea whats the problem with this getting solved.

I am adding the create table and some insert commands:

```
CREATE TABLE employees(emp_id number, emp_name varchar2(25), job_name varchar2(25), manager_id number, hire_date date, salary number, commission number, dep_id number) ;

INSERT INTO employees VALUES(68319,'kayling', 'president', null, 11/18/1991,6000,3100,1001); 
INSERT INTO employees VALUES(66928,'blaze', 'manager', 68319,5/1/1991,2750,3200,3001); 
INSERT INTO employees VALUES(68454,'tucker', 'salesman', 66928,9/8/1991,1600,7000,3001); 
INSERT INTO employees VALUES(65646,'clare', 'manager', 68319, 5/9/1991,2550,2300,1001); 
INSERT INTO employees VALUES(67858,'scarlet', 'analyst', 65646, 1/11/1991,3100,520,2001);
```

Comment: Why are you using a self join?

Comment: I later realized you mean the max netpay amongst those who has a manager. Then simply use manager_id is not null. You would need the join if manager name is a must.

Comment: What "test cases" are not getting cleared? Your query seems fine for getting the employee(s) with the highest salary.

Comment: Hmm I didn't read your SQL before. It is returning that result and correct. Not what you wanted? If why?

Comment: I have used joins coz i want to print the manager name, which is also given in the same table. To find that employee id has to be matched with manager id

Answer (score 1):

You might be missing a trick here in the question asked. The expected result could be "greater than any other employee". This could also mean return those employees who have at least one employee having lesser netpay!! Late, but hope it helps! Enjoy!

```
select e1.emp_name,
       e1.salary,
       e1.commission,
       e1.salary+e1.commission as netpay,
       e2.emp_name as manager_name 
from employees e1 
join employees e2 on e1.manager_id = e2.emp_id 
where e1.salary+e1.commission not in (
  select min(salary+commission)
  from employees where manager_id is not null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the max value and then find the employee(s) matching that pay. ie:

```
SELECT e.emp_name, e.salary, e.commission, (e.salary+e.commission) AS netpay
FROM employees e
where (e.salary + +coalesce(e.commission,0)) = (Select max(salary+coalesce(commission,0)) from Employees where manager_id is not null) and
manager_id is not null;
```

EDIT: This is with manager name:

```
SELECT e.emp_name, e.salary, e.commission, (e.salary+e.commission) AS netpay, x.emp_name as Manager
FROM employees e
inner join employees x on e.manager_id = x.emp_id
where (e.salary + +coalesce(e.commission,0)) = (Select max(salary+coalesce(commission,0)) from Employees where manager_id is not null);
```

[SQL fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d983ab/8)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hierarchical query to get the manager's name (without having read the table twice) and you can use `FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES` to get the people with the highest net salary:

```sql
SELECT emp_name,
       salary,
       commission,
       salary + commission AS netpay,
       PRIOR emp_name AS manager_name
FROM   employees
WHERE  manager_id IS NOT NULL
START WITH manager_id IS NULL
CONNECT BY PRIOR emp_id = manager_id 
ORDER BY netpay DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES;
```

Which, for your sample data, outputs:

> ```
>  EMP_NAME | SALARY | COMMISSION | NETPAY | MANAGER_NAME
>  :--------| -----: | ---------: | -----: | :-----------
>  tucker   |   1600 |       7000 |   8600 | blaze
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=413a8bf62dca4d70f5502c3ad9e5fd2d)*

Answer (score 0):

```
Select
       e.emp_name as "name",
       e.salary as "salary",
       e.commission as "commission",
       nvl2(e.commission,e.salary+e.commission,e.salary)   as "netpay",
       x.emp_name as "Manager name"
from (employees e inner join employees x on e.manager_id = x.emp_id)
 where nvl2(e.commission,e.salary+e.commission,e.salary)  > any (select nvl2(commission,salary+commission,salary) from employees) and x.emp_name is not null ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
   e.emp_name,
   e.salary,
   e.commission,
   e.salary+e.commission NETPAY,
   m.emp_name
FROM employees e
INNER JOIN employees m ON e.manager_id = m.emp_id
WHERE e.salary+e.commission > ANY (SELECT salary+commission FROM 
employees) ;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! When answering questions we recommend adding a bit of explanation about _what the code does_ and _why this is a valid solution to the original problem_ (proof). For more info, see [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) in the FAQ.